# Difficulties understanding the stream's toArray method in java 8

Tags: generics, java-8, java-stream

Why has java decided to throw an `ArrayStoreException` in the following method `<A> A[] Stream<T>.toArray(IntFunction<A[]>)` if the runtime type of any of the stream elements isn't a subtype of the runtime type of the array.

Instead, if the generic type `A` was bounded like in the following `<A super T> A[] Stream<T>.toArray (IntFunction<A[]>)` this will remove the necessity of throwing the exception above and being checked at compile time.